# What time zone should I use for Cape Town

Tags: windows, windows-10, clock, time-zone

I want to add an additional clock for Cape Town.  I know it's in SAST, but I don't know which of the time zones in the drop down correspond to it.

Here are the UTC+02:00 time zones in the dropdown:

[image]

Comment: Its UTC + 2 hours, So any of those will work

Comment: That's not true.  There are different daylight saving rules for different time zones.

Comment: Then add that requirement to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the `(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria` time zone.

Comment: That's not an option.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Sorry, got confused. I edited my answer.

Comment: I checked with someone from Cape Town and they confirmed that they use Harare, Pretoria.